# Drupal 7 error search is unavailable

Tags: search

I have installed the solr integration module 7 with apache solr 3.6.2 for drupal 7 and i seem to get this "Search is temporarily unavailable. If the problem persists, please contact the site administrator." error when i input any words in the serach box and hit enter key .

Not sure why this problem is caused. Solr is able to reach to drupal fine. i was able to index one csv file and was able to query it too.

What is the problem here ?

Comment: Did you copy the schema and other files included in the module to the SOLR instance's conf folder?

Comment: yes i did copy the three files schema.xml,solrconfig.xml and protwords.txt and created corresponding backup files